# Site Attribute Questions (Top 7)

Tags: discussion, top-7, site-attributes

OK, so as the beta testers we're supposed to work on key aspects of the site's attributes.  Taking a cue from other betas, I've made this list so we can easily find them all. I'll also tag the key questions with `[top-7]`

I've made this a CW so anyone can edit it and change these list items into links when the questions are made.

(Some from the [7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/), some from other betas)

- [FAQ (What it should contain)](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq-suggestion) - Please tag using `[faq-suggestion]`
- [Domain Name / Site Name](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1/what-should-our-com-domain-name-be)
- [Site Logo](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/101/discussion-of-site-logo) / [Style](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/102/discussion-of-style)
- [Moderators](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/71/how-should-we-determine-who-will-moderate)
- [404 Image](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/32/404-image-nominations)
- [CAPTCHA Image](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/84/help-select-a-captcha-image)
- What counts as [off topic](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/off-topic) - please tag using `[off-topic]`
- What should the site log look like?
- [How should we promote this site](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/171/help-spread-this-site)?

Thanks for helping out in the beta!

(Text nicked from [meta.photo](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/site-attribute-questions-top-7)).