# Help select a CAPTCHA image

Tags: discussion, top-7, captcha

According to the [Top 7](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/), we need to select a CAPTCHA image, which is the image that gets shown over most in-site CAPTCHA prompts.

So please submit your proposals as answers to this question.

Comment: Reading that page, I don't see any mention of a CAPTCHA. Could you clarify where it says we need this and exactly what it is?

Comment: @mac9416 I think it is the image that shows up when the website asks us to solve a captcha. There is the "Captcha image" on the top and the captcha right below it.

Comment: There is advice on selecting a logo and absolutely nothing about CATCHA at this time in the Top 7 post.

Comment: Please keep the [Ubuntu Brand Guidelines](http://design.canonical.com/the-toolkit/ubuntu-brand-guidelines/) in mind when using the Ubuntu logo.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at the proposed design, making use of our pictogram artwork.

Hopefully, in a bit of a playful way :)

Looking forward to your comments.

[image]

Comment: Haha - I love it!

Comment: simple and beautiful

Answer (score 13):

How about [image: http://ubuntuone.com/p/BYr/]

Please leave some comments too and it's just a prototype

Comment: Maybe we should change Robots to either Machines or Computers.

Comment: The exclamation point seems a little aggressive. I think a regular period would be better.

Comment: Now have the circle of people (ubuntu logi-ish) except one is being pulled out by a cop for being a robot (an obvious robot). LARP style too, no drawings here, I want photos!

Comment: This is okay, but it's a bit boring really... I mean it's just text... (although it is a bit funny)

Answer (score 2):

```
 _________________________________
< Be you human? Or be you machine >
 ---------------------------------
       \ (__)
         (oo)
   /------\/
  / |    ||
 *  /\---/\
    ~~   ~~
```

I though using something from Cowsay would offer a little bit of humor!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little something I started with the model I got [here](http://www.katorlegaz.com/3d_models/miscellaneous/0167/index.php):

[image]

Maybe we can put a funny phrase on the sign like "Penguins Only" or something... ideas are welcome.

Comment: I like it! the gunny phrase could be:

"Hello fellow penguin, please identify yourself as a penguin" or something like it.

Comment: @txwikinger: Hmmm. That's a good idea, except the sign is kind-of small and couldn't have a large phrase on it.

Comment: What about: "Fellow pinguin, please identify!"

Comment: Ugh. Remember the goal: More people using the system. This feels like the geekiest joke imaginable to me.

Comment: "srsly,r u pwngwn?"

Comment: Ubuntu [doesn't really do](http://design.canonical.com/the-toolkit/) the whole penguin thing.