# Nominations for future site logo

Tags: discussion, top-7, site-attributes

According to [this question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/81/site-attribute-questions-top-7) we should start to discuss our future site logo as one of the top-7 items

Comment: Ideas are just as welcome as actual designs.

Answer (score 7):

What about morphing the circle of friends inside the orange dot into a question mark?

I'm no designer by any stretch of the imagination, but hopefully this will give you an idea what I'm thinking.

[image: Question Mark Logo]

Comment: I like it! 15 chars

Comment: Me too! Simple and familiar.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the question mark in icons/logos. I mostly associate it with something missing (e.g. missing icon) than help or questions.

Comment: +1! _` ` ` ` ` `_

Comment: @DoR: As per my comment above, you don't need 15 characters :)

Comment: @li-lo that's weird. I've always seen it as 'questions', and by extension, 'answers'.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe we can shoot the guys over at deviant art a shout. Maybe make a contest for Ubuntu site logo.

I know there a huge Ubuntu theme customizers group over there.

Comment: This is a great idea. And probably, we will get a lot of entries to choose from...