# How should our site be styled?

Tags: discussion, top-7, site-attributes, style

According to [this question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/81/site-attribute-questions-top-7) we should discuss our site's style, including the color scheme and logo. These are a few of the questions we should answer:

- What's the theme of the site? (sophisticated, airy, friendly, etc.)
- What colors should be used on the site?
- What color should the background be?
- What should our logo be? (ideas and rough sketches are fine; most of us aren't artists)

Comment: I'd just like to comment that the AskUbuntu site is extremely good looking. Excellent job!

Answer (score 13):

It would seem to me as though the site should follow the new Ubuntu design. There is a [design document](http://design.canonical.com/the-toolkit/guides-for-websites/) available (supplemental to the [Ubuntu Brand Guidelines](http://design.canonical.com/the-toolkit/ubuntu-brand-guidelines/)) that outlines all the different logos, colors, and various elements and their meaning.

Comment: Some details here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Brand

Comment: +1 because this is the best idea ever!

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Brand2#Web%20Themes that's probably the best go

Comment: This is the one I was thinking about: http://design.canonical.com/the-toolkit/guides-for-websites/

Answer (score 7):

[Website style guide](http://design.canonical.com/the-toolkit/guides-for-websites/) from the Canonical Design team.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think some branding ala the Canonical standards is needed for the header to ensure users realise it is an officially supported Ubuntu site. However, I also think keeping it clean and simple like now is **very very** important because the basic stack overflow/exchange schemes are part of their success.

Therefore I would suggest the Logo strip be used, although I have to say I quite like the current light blue sketched logo!

How about half way between the two?

Comment: We've got someone from the Canonical design team working with the SE design person. Check out the status thread: http://meta.ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/323/finishing-the-beta-off-strong-the-plan-so-far