# Help spread this site....

Tags: discussion, top-7, promote

Please help us promote this site... I know there are some ways  in the sidebar. But can you come up with more interesting ways to promote this site?

The SE folks have a post on how to help spread a site: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/

Now this site also has its own URL: https://askubuntu.com/

By the way, now the short links http://bit.ly/askubuntu and http://j.mp/askubuntu link to this site. So, you can use those to spread this site using twitter etc.

Comment: Merged! Should we clean up theses comments? They don't make sense anymore.

Comment: @tx: Sure... or have you done that yet?

Comment: Make sure to include in your post that askubuntu.com is the new domain.

Answer (score 6):

I've made an [instructive screencast](http://ubuntudevelopers.blip.tv/file/4081707/) for new users.

Answer (score 5):

I've updated all my clients websites to spawn obtrusive javascript popup windows yelling at visitors who run Ubuntu with: "YOU NEED TO VISIT THIS SITE"

But in all seriousness those of the members here who are more social should bring the site up whenever appropriate. For instance at several monthly meetups I try to bring up this site to other Ubuntu users and other who are interested in taking the first step - word of mouth can be a powerful thing.

For those members who are more into (micro)blogging I've been blowing up my Twitter feed (when appropriate) about the site as a lot of followers of mine use Linux or Ubuntu in some faucet.

On forums I've added my "Flair" badge for this Ubuntu stackexchange to help attract other users to the site. This is especially helpful on technology forums (and the Ubuntu Forums) it's a more subtle way to promote this site without having potential backlash as "spamming".

--- Added some time later

In addition to bringing the site to your blogs, feeds, and forums - bring them to events: Bug-crushing session with your Ubuntu LoCo, At an event representing Ubuntu, anywhere people who use the OS and would listen to you.

Lastly when we move out of Beta and (hopefully) secure ask.ubuntu.com I think shirts (deep purple/white text or old school brown/white) with just the text ask.ubuntu.com would be just as effective.

Comment: You can include the following picture in any signature that allows images to be embedded and it will automatically update every 24 hours with your reputation: http://stackimage.quickmediasolutions.com/flair.php?id=41&site=ubuntu.stackexchange&background=eeeeee&border=ffffff&text=555555&title=5555ff&font1=sans&font2=sansbold

Comment: Actually, I think I'll turn that into an answer :)

Comment: can you update this; one I picked up is "when we get out of Beta".

Answer (score 5):

The best way I can think of is to put a copy of [StackImage Flair](https://stackapps.com/questions/847/stackimage-generating-images-of-questions-and-users) on your blog or in your signatures on forums.

**What is StackImage?**

It's a small image that stays up to date with your current reputation on this site:

*Examples:*

http://stackimage.quickmediasolutions.com/flair.php?id=5&site=askubuntu&background=eeeeee&border=ffffff&text=555555&title=5555ff&font1=sans&font2=sansboldhttp://stackimage.quickmediasolutions.com/flair.php?id=4&site=askubuntu&border=ffffff&background=3b5998&text=ffffff&title=dddddd&font1=serif&font2=serifitalic

**Where can I get it?**

Just visit [stackimage.quickmediasolutions.com](http://stackimage.quickmediasolutions.com) and follow the instructions.

**How does it work?**

StackImage fetches your current reputation using the API and creates an image based on the parameters supplied in the URL as follows:

<kbd>http://stackimage.quickmediasolutions.com/flair.php**?options**</kbd>

```
[Required]
  id         - the desired user id
  site       - the desired SE site (in this case 'askubuntu')

[Optional]
  background - the color of the background
  border     - the color of the border
  text       - the color of the text
  title      - the color of the user's name
  font1      - the font to be used for the badges *
  font2      - the font to be used for the display name and rep *

* can be one of [mono,  monobold,  monobolditalic,  monoitalic,
                 sans,  sansbold,  sansbolditalic,  sansitalic,
                 serif, serifbold, serifbolditalic, serifitalic]
```

Comment: How do those images explain that the site is for answering questions about Ubuntu? If I saw that on someone's blog, I would have no idea what the image was for.

Comment: @Erigami: True... it would need to be used in conjunction with a label indicating what it was. Also, once we get a logo, it will be a little more clear.

Comment: @George Feature request: I tried it as a forum signature but it's a bit too much, especially with the forum already having my picture on it. How about a slim version with no picture, something that fit's around one line, similar to the top of the site: [logo] Jorge Castro 1,342 *2 *13

Comment: @Jorge: Good idea. Hopefully I can put something like that together tomorrow.

Comment: @Jorge: Okay, I've added a new 'mini' edition. Just change the 'flair.php' in the URL to 'mini.php' and you're good to go. Everything else is the same. Please let me know if it works for you!

Comment: @George It looks great! But looks like it doesn't work in the ubuntu forums. I'll got ask one of their moderators to see what is up.

Comment: @Jorge: Try adding `&ext=.jpg` to the end of the URL. Sometimes forums don't like images without a '.jpg' or '.png' extension. This should fix that.

Comment: There's also an 'official' version of the [image based flair](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/flair-now-even-flairier/) now.

Comment: @Simon: I know :P

Answer (score 5):

Existing Ubuntu mailing lists and forums have a good amount of traffic, perhaps having a signature tagline in people's email signature will help spread the word. For example

```
Joe Smith
me@ubuntu.com
Questions about Ubuntu? Ask the experts at http://askubuntu.com
```

Also a link in IRC on your /quit and /away messages

Comment: Forum signatures as well.

Answer (score 4):

For those members here who are connected to the wider Ubuntu community, it might be useful to find opportunities for *specific* promotions. That is, to promote participation in answering a particular question on the Ubuntu Stack Exchange. (It might also work in reverse, prompting someone to ask a particular question here.)

It would take some additional effort to choose (and possibly summarize) a top notch question, but a user of this site who is also syndicated on the Ubuntu Planet could blog about a question here and invite people to come check it out. Of course, bloggers syndicated on other aggregators or who are have a few readers, and users of twitter, identi.ca, facebook, etc. could certainly do the same.

I figure this would work for several kinds of interesting questions:

- community wiki questions (usually open to more answers)
- really interesting questions with good answers
- interesting questions that need a better answer (probably the most useful for site improvement)

Recently I noticed a [blog post](http://ubuntulinuxtipstricks.blogspot.com/2010/08/what-are-barriers-to-walking.html) by [maco](https://askubuntu.com/users/1158/maco) about [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2872/what-are-the-biggest-barriers-to-walking-the-motu-developer-path) from this site which is a pretty good community-wiki-style question (no obvious definitive answer) although not marked as such.

Comment: If you run into good examples let me know and I can post it on planet.

Comment: @JorgeCastro A few interesting lists to look at are: [questions with 0 answers, sorted by votes](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=answers%3a0), [newest questions with 10+ votes](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=votes%3a10), or [active questions with 10+ votes](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=votes%3a10).

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu teams participate in conferences around the world. For larger events such as FOSDEM, ScALE, etc. many teams already run Ubuntu booths. Some of these events are huge (French release parties have been known to top 5,000 people).

At OLF I put a simple "For ubuntu questions ask the experts at http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com" sign next to the business cards and opened the browser to an existing question an answer for a question I felt people would ask alot at the booth.

The existing Ubuntu Local Teams have an [event lister](http://loco.ubuntu.com/events/) of Ubuntu related events happening all over the world. Perhaps someone can volunteer to get in touch with upcoming teams having events.

Comment: I think this is a great idea. Showing people who are interested in Ubuntu that there is a place for just asking questions can really work for both us and Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

SE has a feature which allows people to [tweet and facebook](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/) their questions to their social networks. This serves two goals, it helps spread the site AND hopefully gets the person some exposure on their question.

Answer (score 2):

I think a widget, similar to the countdown widgets and the 10.04 widget that Jono Bacon has on [his site](http://www.jonobacon.org/) (check it out on the left hand side) that we could just leave lying around on our websites would be a good way to passively promote the site. The user flair widgets don't say what the site is, so aren't really a good option for this.

Answer (score 1):

I think a lot of the main marketing push relies on the site coming out of beta and getting a proper (something.ubuntu.com) domain. Until then it looks very unofficial.

Other than that, we need to get listed in the main support sections. We'd be competing with Launchpad Answers so I'm not sure how feasible that is but it's important to the long-term success of this place.

We already have the search engine crowd. Several posts here rank top in Google.

Comment: Who says becoming official is a goal?

Answer (score 1):

We have some excerpts from Jono's book on building community that might be useful here:

- [Building Buzz](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BuildingCommunity/KnowledgeBase#Building%20Buzz)

and Fedora maintains a great list of [press publications](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Marketing_press_publications) if someone wants to go down that route.

Answer (score -2):

Please promote this site: http://ubuntu.shapado.com/

Perhaps I should have been a bit more verbose. 
While I am a big fan of SO in general, I think it is unfortunate to be basing a FLOSS community around a non-FLOSS windows centered stack.

I also believe that in denying the community the ability to decide where to direct revenue (from advertising fx) we are doing ourselves and the mission a disservice.

While it is true that we might be able to grow faster due to cross pollination from other StackExchange venues, the arguments related to google juice are without much merit, askubuntu is on its own domain and gains no benefit from being in the SE fold (apart from cross links).

In terms of promotion, we are in the start phase and could easily direct efforts at a FLOSS platform instead.

I hope this is not construed as an attack on the efforts of the people who worked at making askubuntu happen, I think you have done an amazing job and the site looks great :)

I have no doubt that you will succeed in making it the 'go to resource', which is precisely why I ask you to think twice and consider if we can't do one better, be it with shapado, [osqa](http://www.osqa.net/gallery/) or something else entirely.

Much love -- unomi

Comment: Why so many downvotes...

Comment: Probably because it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Sometimes a good answer constitutes pointing out flaws in the question.