# Reception of askubuntu.com

Tags: discussion, promote

Now that this site has officially launched (no longer in beta), I think it'd be interesting to see what people elsewhere (outside the usual Stack Exchange circles) are saying.

Have you noticed askubuntu.com being talked about at a forum, or mentioned at a prominent site?

(I'm not sure, but I guess this is on-topic enough here on Meta... And of course this is closely related to [promoting the site](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/171/help-spread-this-site).)

Answer (score 4):

[OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/) ran this story:
[“Ask Ubuntu” Stack Exchange site out of beta, new awesome domain](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/10/ask-ubuntu-stack-exchange-site-out-of-beta-new-awesome-domain/)

The post itself and most comments are very positive.

Answer (score 2):

There's an interesting thread at Ubuntu Forums:
[askubuntu.com - what do you think?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1591890)

(Even though the opening post is very negative (some might say a flamebait), note that many misconceptions have already been [rebutted](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9946940&postcount=10).)

Comment: I've participated a little, but it seriously bugs me that you can't upvote good posts... :) +1 for insightful observations at [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9949272&postcount=79).

Comment: That thread is going to get _hot_ once people find out [this site runs on Windows, C#, ASP.net, LINQ and what not](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/). Good luck passing the point that's because of [pragmatic reasons](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/05/giving-up-on-microsoft.html). :)

Comment: Indeed, especially when you consider: http://ubuntu.shapado.com/ which has none of those issues.

Comment: Heh, "ubuntu ask", almost identical names and all. Of course, that site doesn't seem to have the "issue" of a critical mass of users either, even if it runs on kosher FOSS stack. (But maybe I shouldn't underestimate what religious zealotry can achieve when let loose...) :-)

Comment: @Jonik, That's ridiculously unfair to the folks at ubuntu.shapado.com They were running that site before the Ubuntu site started in Area 51 here. It's not like they up and started it out of "religious zealotry" after this one.

Comment: @badp isn't part of the point of both Ubuntu and Stack Overflow that we can all get along and learn from each other *regardless* of petty differences like religion, I mean, technology stack?

Comment: @Jeff it is, for me :)

Comment: @andrewsomething: That was a tongue-in-cheek comment in reference to badp's amusing observation above and the thread on Ubuntu Forums (where some zealotry *is* going on), not so much about the Shapado site itself.

Comment: For the record, I'd also rather see both Ubuntu & SO as being about "humanity towards others" and such things, instead of petty factionalism. :-)

Comment: First off, let me say that I am a fan of SO, I browse it frequently and try to help where I can. That said, I find the derision intended with 'religious zealotry', 'factionalism' and its ilk as willfully ignoring the history of Ubuntu. Ubuntu would never have existed if it wasn't for the zealous pursuance of 'libre' software. To try to paint that as a quaint notion of some weirdos is to discount the value of Ubuntu itself. This isn't about me thinking that Jeff is a fascist capitalist pig, I am sure he is a swell guy :) It's about continuing to build 'libre' value.