# Searching for "help ubuntu" or "ubuntu+help" in Google search should list Ask Ubuntu in results

Tags: support

I think the two search strings `help ubuntu` or `ubuntu+help` should bring up Ask Ubuntu website in the search results. It does not feature in the first three pages of Google search.

What do you think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't really have control of what Google Search does. Many people try to game it (and some even succeed at least in the short term)

However these days I am finding AU questions and answers coming up more and more in my google searches (within minutes in some cases).

The way to ensure this always works long term is:

- Continue to provide high quality questions and answers
- Ensure that we're doing a good job with editing and tagging
- [Help spread this site](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/171/help-spread-this-site).
- Keep working with new users to help them figure out the site and how to contribute.

If we keep doing core quality-level things the rest will work itself out. The better the content is, the more people will link, the more people link, the better we'll do in search engines, the better we do in search engines, the more people we have contributing content (and so on...)