# Moderator Pro Tempore

Tags: discussion, moderation

This community needs to start contributing some names they would like to act as provisional Moderators. Please read this: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)**.

Here are some basic guidelines:

- Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity ([see this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150/elect-our-provisional-moderators) for reference).
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer, adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves.
- Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.

Here is what we are looking for in a Moderator...

We are seeing out members who are deeply engaged in the community’s development; members who:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in A Theory of Moderation.

Bonus points for:

- Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
- Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
- Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

Comment: Uh... I'm still not sure about that self-nomination thing.

Comment: Has anyone let the people nominated know that they have been nominated so that they can check in and let everyone know whether or not they accept the nomination?

Comment: @Ressu: Good idea. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @Robert: What happens after the mods are chosen?

Comment: @George Edison: Candidates will be contacted to see who is interested, selections made, given access to Moderator chat room, given mod access with some basic guidelines to get started, announced in meta. There's not a lot of process in becoming a Mod. It's primarily a learn-as-you-go experience. Mostly covered [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

Comment: @Robert: Can we get an idea of when this will happen?

Comment: Start about 14 days after launch. It's all here: [Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)

Answer (score 13):

**User**: [txwikinger](https://askubuntu.com/users/4/txwikinger)
**Meta account**: [txwikinger](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/4/txwikinger)

**Reason**: txwikinger has been participating heavily and is a long-time contributor to Ubuntu and Kubuntu.

Comment: +1 According to his profile, he's a Canadian.

Comment: Thanks for the trust. I accept the nomination.

Answer (score 12):

**User:** [lfaraone](https://askubuntu.com/users/66/lfaraone)
**Meta account:** [lfaraone](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/66/lfaraone)

**Reason**: lfaraone is a Ubuntu and Debian developer. His answers are well-written and concise. He is also active on the Meta site.

Comment: Much appreciated. I accept the nomination. NB: I'm currently at the Debian Developer Conference in NYC, so I will be intermittently active throughout the week.

Comment: @lfa: Congrats on becoming a DD!

Answer (score 8):

**User:** [George Edison](https://askubuntu.com/users/5/george-edison)
**Meta account:** [George Edison](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/5/george-edison)

**Reason:** George is has been very active from the beginning of this beta, also in helping new users to stackexchange with comments. He also has experience with the concept of stackoverflow et al.

Comment: Why, thank you! I humbly accept.

Comment: The two people who voted against George should explain their reasons. If you have concerns you should share them.

Comment: I downvoted based on his observed behavior on Meta.SO. He may be a fine person, but I'm not sure his personality is well-suited to the job.

Comment: @mmyers: I understand your concern... but Meta needs to be taken with a grain of salt. I joke around on there... just like everyone else. I can be serious when it counts - like here. Can you explain a little more what you mean by my "personality?"

Comment: @George: Well, for one thing, it's sometimes hard to tell when you're joking. You've managed to (rightly or wrongly) come off as somewhat arrogant, which is generally a negative quality in a moderator. You kept asking "fun" questions even though a) no one thought they were funny and b) you were asked to stop (though to be fair, this hasn't happened for several months now). You have made personal attacks on other users. Shall I go on?

Comment: @George: Anyway, I'm sure the ones who pick the moderators are familiar with all this. That's why I didn't feel it necessary to comment at first.

Comment: @mmyers: Well, I admit I got a bit carried away with the jokes, but I was asked to stop, and I did stop. And any percieved arrogance was probably a joke too. As mentioned, Meta isn't very serious.

Comment: And as for the "personal attacks", I merely pointed out some negative behavior by certain individuals.

Answer (score 8):

**User:** [Evan](https://askubuntu.com/users/46/evan)
**Meta account:** [Evan](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/46/evan)

**Reason:** He started this mess. :) On a more serious note, on the technical side Evan works on the installer and as a member of the Foundations team he has real good knowledge of the guts of the system. On the SE side he's an experienced stack user so he has a good level of understanding on what this site should be about (see his comments on the area51 proposal)

Comment: Jorge, please link to the accounts.

Answer (score 5):

**User:** [Marco Ceppi](https://askubuntu.com/users/41/marco-ceppi)
**Meta account:** [Marco Ceppi](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/13045/marco-ceppi)

**Reason:** I am long time Ubuntu Adapter (Since 4.10), also a Senior Linux System Administrator at my place of employment monitoring and administrating Ubuntu machines (As well as other distros). I am interested in helping this community grow and become a strong StackExchange site.

I am a member of my Ubuntu LoCo [Washing DC LoCo](http://dc.ubuntu-us.org/)

Answer (score 2):

**User:** [garbagecollector](https://askubuntu.com/users/333/garbagecollector)
**Meta account:**  [garbagecollector](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/333/garbagecollector)

**Reason:** I have been using Ubuntu for about 3 years off and on. I am learning things everyday. I have photographic memory so I can spot duplicates a mile away. I would love the opportunity to help this stack grow, and learn from all the questions, and answer when I can.

Another Canadian here too! :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

**User**: [qbi](https://askubuntu.com/users/236/qbi)
**Meta**: [qbi](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/236/qbi)

**Reason**: I'm a long term Debian user (+10y) and also use Ubuntu for at least four years. Mainly I administer a small PC pool and a handful of servers. I'm with the site since its initial beta phase and will try to help other people using Ubuntu (and of course Debian).

Answer (score -2):

**User:** [MichealH](https://askubuntu.com/users/456)
**Meta Account:** [MichealH](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/456)

**Reason:** I have been using Ubuntu for at least 4 years now. I have some strong bonds in the community. I have been supporting people on the Ubuntu Forums for at least one year now and Have been very active in the community there. Not only have I supported people, I get involved in many projects and I help out Loco's. I package and I do a bit of Wiking! Also I am on the computer and around the internet (on average) 16 hours so I can cover as much of This site and The forums ect.

I'm from Britain by the way!

Cheers in advance :D

MichealH

Comment: you have not much rep...